# First Undefined Variable then Undefined offset

Tags: php

I have a problem with fixing undefined variable. I've also tried to use `isset` but it's not working.

Errors:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'dir'
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0
Warning: Illegal string offset 'dir'
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

Code:

```
$page = ""; 
define("IN_SYSTEM", TRUE);

if(strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],"Win") == false){ $page['dir'] = 
str_replace('\\','/',$page['dir']); }
chdir(str_replace($page['dir'], "", getcwd()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You define $page as a String. Then you try to access an array key, that can not work. You never define $page as an array or fill the key "dir". What are you trying to do here?